# how to remove the background of a contour using OpenCV in Android?

Tags: java, android, opencv, ocr

Sample Token Scanned: https://ibin.co/3irqGlxXezL3.jpg

Input Image: https://ibin.co/3irmfXKjYocz.jpg

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXL5f.png)

As you can see I have applied .submat but I'm not sure why is it masking the inners of the contour instead of the outer surface. Moreover, filtering the largest contour is also not consistent. Any ideas on how can I make it more robust based on the dimensions of the ticket as my aim is to scan tickets with very same dimensions.

As a newbie OpenCV enthusiast, I want someone to guide me with my final mission here, which is to get the year, month, date, and time from the calender in the ticket and show it in text form.

The ticket will have punched holes as markings. So, what I have in mind is to track each (hole) blob and extract it along with it's surrounding digits to know which number it was based on its surrounding, and do this to all of the blobs (holes) with some hierarchy in place to know if the extraction was from the 'year' field or month or day field respectively. Or is there any other better approach for this?

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat srcMat = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat processedMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, processedMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(processedMat, processedMat, new Size(3, 3), 0);
    Imgproc.threshold(processedMat, processedMat, 98, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(processedMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Log.e(TAG, "ContourSize: " + contours.size());
    double maxVal = 0;
    int maxValIdx = 0;
    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
        double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
        if (maxVal < contourArea) {
            maxVal = contourArea;
            maxValIdx = contourIdx;
        }
    }
    Imgproc.drawContours(srcMat, contours, maxValIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), -2);
    if (!contours.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e("largestContour", "" + contours.get(maxValIdx));
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(maxValIdx));
        srcMat.submat(rect);
    }
    return srcMat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

first of all you are using the overloaded version of the [drawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#drawContours-org.opencv.core.Mat-java.util.List-int-org.opencv.core.Scalar-int-) method.
The negative thickness means that a filled countour will be drawn.

Thus, try change -2 to a positive number to get the contour as desired.

Now let me try to say what would be my first approach for detect these dates on the ticket:

1) transform you contour to a perpendicular view with perpective transform:

[image]

See this [example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) in Python.

2) Use blob detection to find your blobs:

[image]

See this [example](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) in Python and C++.

It should works if you have a well defined model of ticket layout.

Comment: I have tried changing the thickness to a positive number and by doing that, it only outlines the Token like so: https://ibin.co/3isRy2LSEwHn.png and is not separating the background, I guess this is first step in moving forward as I must have to separate the token to be able to apply the rest.

Comment: Yes. It is as expected. The drawing function is just useful to feedback you about the contour region. Now, try to play with poligons in order to realize the required vertices https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html and than apply the perspective transformation.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding tutorials or examples in java for my use and can't get my around python example either. 

Is there some sort of a dimension filter which I can apply to my token contour to make it more consistent, right now it shifts places and draws uneven and incomplete contours as well, can you help me with masking to making the rest of the image blur or something to make the token pop out of the background. And I'm having hard time in applying the perspective transformation to crop the token out of the image for further processing....

Comment: Google results are inspiring: https://github.com/badlogic/opencv-fun/blob/master/src/pool/tests/PerspectiveTransform.java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688491/opencv-getperspectivetransform-and-warpperspective-java http://answers.opencv.org/question/102464/android-opencv-perspective-transformation-not-working-as-expected/

Comment: I'm still having hard time applying warp perception to the token contour, however I have managed to crop the token using submat, although it is also  giving the neighbouring area as well, as it is cropping the rectangle as a square.

Comment: What are the ticket actual dimensions?

Comment: The actual dimensions of the token is:  846x2408

I have made some progress though, please check this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611281/opencv-deskewing-a-contour